# How to determine when fancybox is open?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I need to know that fancybox has been open up that to allow or deny another function to start.

Build-in functions Fancybox like 'onStart' or 'onClosed' not work.

I'm talking about version 1.3.0 RC2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The version your using apparently doesn't match the documentation; I looked at the source and saw the names of the options were different the the online docs. I just tested the following with 1.3RC2:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function myStartFunction() { alert('fancy box opened'); }

    $("a#inline").fancybox({
        'onStart': myStartFunction
    });  
});
```

The option you're looking for is 'onStart' - the alert in myStartFunction goes off every time I open a box. I'm not sure when they changed the option but you can look at the source of any version you use at the bottom, and see what the option should be called.

**EDIT**

I just double checked on v1.2.5 - the version I use - and the callbacks are indeed named different. callbackOnStart works with 1.25 but, as I said, not 1.3

Comment: Haha, if you can see in source of http://fancybox.net/dev/130/ they call an 'onStart' and etc from second param. That way it not work. Thanks a lot Erik ^^

Answer (score 13):

`$.fancybox.isOpen` (bool) indicates, whether fancybox is open.

Comment: better and pretty solution, should be answer

Comment: For some reason this returns undefined when it is open.

Answer (score 8):

Try to use methods

```
beforeLoad, // Before loading
afterLoad, // After loading
beforeShow, // Before changing in current item
afterShow, // After opening
```

This code work fine

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({beforeShow:function(){alert('blah');}});
```

Comment: The OP says `I'm talking about version 1.3.0 RC2`

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a way to determine whether fancybox is open or not (instead of an event that is fired upon opening fancybox) then as of fancybox v2 you can use the `$.fancybox.isOpen` property. It's not documented (at least I didn't find any reference) but it works.

**Example:**

```
if(!$.fancybox.isOpen) {
    $.fancybox.open({
        href: '#newsletter-campaign-popup',
        height: 385,
        width: 510,
        type: 'inline'
    });
}
```

The example above prevents opening a second fancybox if one is already open.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by built-in functions. Fancybox has callbacks which call user-defined functions (that you must make yourself).
Like:

```
function myClose()
{
    alert('close');
}

function myStart()
{
    alert('start');
}

$("a#single_image").fancybox({
     'callbackOnClose': myClose,
     'callbackOnStart': myStart
// etc, etc..
});
```

Alternatively you could check the `fancy_content` div to see if it has anything inside.
(if it has, then fancybox is open).

```
if ( $('#fancy_content:empty').length > 0 )
{
  // Is empty
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this seems to work for me:

```
        isLoaded : function(){
            return $('#fancybox-content').html()!='';
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple div's that you are using for fancybox, following code might be better and more universal solution:

```
if ($('.fancybox-opened').length == 0) {
  //there is no fancybox opened at all
}
```

Note also that fancybox content might not be always empty, even if fancybox is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for 2018 December.

```
if ($('.fancybox-content').length == 0) {
    //there is no fancybox opened at all
}
```

Details:

```js
    function checkf()
    {
        if ($('.fancybox-content').length == 0) {
            alert('there is no fancybox opened at all.');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('there is a fancybox opened.');
        }
    }
    $("#ffbox").click(function()
    {
        setTimeout(checkf,1000);
    });
    checkf();
```

```html
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.2/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.2/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a data-fancybox data-options='{"iframe" : {"css" : {"width" : "80%", "height" : "80%"}}}' href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=China" class="btn btn-primary" id="ffbox">Display Google Map</a>
    </body>
```