# FancyBox, getting ajax to fire on window load/click

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I'm trying to get a fancybox window to come up on click after an ajax call.  I can do that fine with

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() { 

    //FancyBox image zoom functionality jQuery script
    $("a.aboutContentImage").fancybox({
        'zoomOpacity': true,
        'zoomSpeedIn': 300,
        'zoomSpeedOut': 300,
        'overlayShow': true,
        'frameWidth': 800,
        'frameHeight': 600
    }); 
});
```

I should note that `a.aboutContentImage` is not present on the page until after that ajax call.

Then after the windows has opened, I need to load in some text from an ajax call. I've tried

```
$("a.aboutContentImage").live("click", function(e) {

    // ajax here
});
```

But there's some sort of compatibility issue with trying to put an event listener on a fancybox object.

Comment: You want to load the text inside the fancy box? Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128652/how-to-determine-when-fancybox-is-open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, why not just add the text to the image title? Fancybox automatically add the title into a caption. If you need to do something else, then try using the Fancybox `onComplete` callback ([ref](http://fancybox.net/api))? I haven't tested this, but it should work:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() { 
  //FancyBox image zoom functionality jQuery script
  $("a.aboutContentImage").fancybox({
    'zoomOpacity': true,
    'zoomSpeedIn': 300,
    'zoomSpeedOut': 300,
    'overlayShow': true,
    'frameWidth': 800,
    'frameHeight': 600,
    'onComplete' : function(){
      // do whatever here
      var txt = $('#text').text();
      $('#fancybox-title-float-main')
        .append(txt)
        .show();
    }
  }); 
});
```

Adding to the `#fancybox-title-float-main` will add on text to the end of whatever is in the title attribute. So you may want to use `.html()` instead of `.append()` or whatever.

Comment: Hmm, ok if you don't have a title attribute for the image, the `#fancybox-title-float-main` div doesn't exist, so you could add the content to the `#fancybox-title`, but then you'd have to add some css styling for it. Another solution would be to add the content to the `#fancybox-content`, where the image resides, but then you'd need to change the image height to not be `100%` and add the height of the text to the content window - more of a pain really.

Comment: Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/UagVd/9/)... but without all the ajaxy stuff.

Comment: It's pulling in forms, images, etc, things that cannot fit nor should be in the title.

Comment: Then add it to the `#fancybox-content`

Comment: This won't work because this is a group. ie multiple aboutContentImage's each needing specific content.

Comment: Ok... what exactly are you trying to do inside of fancybox? Maybe you can show/hide specific content - which as I stated is inside of the `#fancybox-content` container. Share some HTML?